# how to get value from text file by excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have a text file with information like

> {"status":200,"source_coordinates":[[52.55407,13.160621]],"destination_coordinates":[[52.431237,13.720644],[52.55409,13.720557],[52.55407,13.160621]],"distance_table":[[31574,30971,0]]}

and I'd like to have a table in excel with

```
columns status, source, destination, distance_table and theirs values.
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Text to columns? Convert texto csv then import? Regex?

Comment: **Help us to help you.** Post your current code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Open file For Input As #1
Text = ""
  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    Text = Text & textline
  Loop

  Close #1
```

With that, you have all data in variable 'text'. Now you can fill the data into the appropiate columns with InStr.